# How do I get @vimeo/player to work on my Angular2/Typescript project?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, typescript2.0, vimeo-player

### Question:

How do I get [@vimeo/player](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js) to work on my Angular2/Typescript project (specifically Ionic2) ?

### Description:

Trying to get the [vimeo player](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js) to work with Angular2/Typescript.

```
npm install --save @vimeo/player
```

According to their documentation the library can be used like so:

> If you’re using a module bundler like webpack or rollup, the exported
>   object will be the Player constructor (unlike the browser where it is
>   attached to window.Vimeo):

```
import Player from '@vimeo/player';

const player = new Player('handstick', {
    id: 19231868,
    width: 640
});

player.on('play', function() {
    console.log('played the video!');
});
```

Which looks super promising ! But doesn't work.

### What I've tried:

I've installed [`@vimeo/player`](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js) and [`@types/vimeo__player`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/vimeo__player)
I created a player component in my Ionic2 app.

**player.ts:**

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from "ionic-angular/index";

//noinspection TypeScriptCheckImport,TypeScriptCheckImport
import Player from "@vimeo/player";


@Component({
  selector: 'player-component',
  templateUrl: 'player.html'
})
export class PlayerComponent {

  @ViewChild('player_container') playerContainer;
  private player: Player;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController){}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // child is set
    this.player = new Player(this.playerContainer);
    console.log(Player);
  }

}
```

***I use view child, but I've also tried with the element's ID.***

**player.html**

```
<div #player_container></div>
```

And get the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: You must pass either a valid element
>   or a valid id. Player@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:102846:32
>   ngAfterViewInit@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:74715:80
>   callProviderLifecycles@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:11417:33
>   callElementProvidersLifecycles@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:11392:35
>   callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:11376:47
>   checkAndUpdateView@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:12408:36
>   callWithDebugContext@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:13462:47
>   detectChanges@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:10474:81
>   _viewAttachToDOM@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:43884:53 _transition@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:43976:34 onInvoke@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:4406:43
>   run@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:4146
>   http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:13734
>   onInvokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:4397:47
>   runTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:4841
>   o@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:1898
>   invoke@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10674

*As you can see it compiles but crashes at runtime.*

**@types/vimeo__player** Just doesn't seem to be finished, and doesn't even seem to be noticed when I import `@vimeo/player`

The [issue on github regarding vimeo__player](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/15593) seems show that this is true.

> It looks like module resolution is correctly resolving it as a JS
>   module, but only because it didn't find the types first. Are you sure
>   you've correctly included those types? --listFiles would show you if
>   it's lincluded.

### Extras:

[Issued opened on Vimeo's github player page.](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js/issues/144)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your problem is not caused by `@types/vimeo__player` neither it is related to your build system/configuration.

TypeScript type definitions never, *never*, **never** affect runtime's behaviour. Even compile-time errors have no other effect than displaying red in the console, the JavaScript will still be emitted.

Looking at the stack trace you've got, we can also say that `Player` is effectively imported, and since you're saying that there is no compile-time error, everything is good on the build aspect of the things.

In fact, the error says it all: `TypeError: You must pass either a valid element or a valid id.`.

`Player` says that it expects an `HTMLElement`.

The problem is, you are using `@ViewChild()` from Angular. This decorator will return a wrapper when you are querying on a native element. This wrapper is of type `ElementRef`, and has a property named `nativeElement` that contains the original, DOM element.

So instead of doing this:

```
this.player = new Player(this.playerContainer);
```

Do this:

```
this.player = new Player(this.playerContainer.nativeElement);
```

But you may now think *"why TypeScript didn't produced a type error since I'm not passing a native element ?"*. That's a good question, I don't have enough data to be sure, but I think that your import may be incorrect.

Instead of:

```
//noinspection TypeScriptCheckImport,TypeScriptCheckImport
import Player from "@vimeo/player";
```

Can you try to do this?

```
import { Player } from '@vimeo/player';
```

Looking at the .d.ts file, it looks like that Player is a named export. But you're right, the type definitions of @vimeo/player are incomplete, or not in sync with the JavaScript library. You should be aware of that type of problems in TypeScript, although this does not happen everyday ;)

Comment: `this.player = new Player(this.playerContainer.nativeElement);` did it for me.  `{Player}` throws the following error `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not a constructor`

Comment: That confirms your impression, @types/vimeo__player is not in sync with the library as it seems that the latter now exports Player as the default export, while TS thinks it's a named export. Keep your `noinspection` comment for now and watch for updates on the @types package (yarn outdated / npm outdated).

Answer (score 5):

For a standard [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) project this import statement works.

```
import * as Player from "@vimeo/player/dist/player.js";
```

Comment: works in angular ivy, throws an error if following the docs. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In case your ViewChild is undefined (due to a lazy load, etc), you can try this:

- ViewChild**ren** instead of ViewChild;
- Wait DOM be available before running your code;

Code:

```
import { Component, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';
import Player from "@vimeo/player";


@Component({
  selector: 'player-component',
  templateUrl: 'player.html'
})
export class PlayerComponent {

  private player: Player;
  @ViewChildren('player_container') playerContainer;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    /* wait DOM be available */
    this.playerContainer.changes.subscribe(item => {
        if (this.playerContainer.length) {
            /* DOM AVAILABLE */
            this.player = new Player(this.playerContainer.first.nativeElement);

            this.player.on('play', function() {
                console.log('played the video!');
            });

            this.player.getVideoTitle().then(function(title) {
                console.log('title:', title);
            });
        }
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to their documentation

> When the library loads, it will scan your page for elements with Vimeo **attributes**. Each element must have at least a **data-vimeo-id** or **data-vimeo-url** attribute in order for the embed to be created automatically.

so basically it needs a div tag with either "data-vimeo-id" attribute or "data-video-url" attribute with valid values asiigned, before calling the player's constructor.

so You can use **attribute binding** to assign the video id(to data-vimeo-id) or video url (to data-video-url) to the div tag in your template file.

```html
<div [attr.data-vimeo-id]="videoId"> </div>
```

and assign the video id of the video you want to embed to the variable "videoId" in the Typescript file (in ngOninit).
same can be done with url also in that case [attr.data-vimeo-url]="videoUrl";